# need to pass data from dataservice to component in angular 4?

Tags: angular, rest, http, typescript

**Create-project Component;**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

import { Scenario } from './step1TS/scenario';
import { Complainces} from './step1TS/complainces';
import { Budget } from './step1TS/budget';
import { Size } from './step1TS/size';
import { Duration } from './step1TS/duration';
import { Role } from './step1TS/role';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-projects',
    templateUrl: './create-projects.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-projects.component.css']
})
export class CreateProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
    results : String[];
    selectedScenario : Scenario = new Scenario('Select A Scenario','');
    scenarios = [
    new Scenario('Select A Scenario',''),
    new Scenario('Scenario1','sc1'),
    new Scenario('Scenario2','sc2'), 
    new Scenario('Scenario3','sc3'),
    new Scenario('Scenario4','sc4'),
    new Scenario('Scenario5','sc5'),
    new Scenario('Scenario6','sc6')
    ]
    selectedComplainces : Complainces = new Complainces('Type Of Complainces','');
    complainces = [
    new Complainces('Type Of Complainces',''),
    new Complainces('Complainces1','c1'),
    new Complainces('Complainces2','c2'), 
    new Complainces('Complainces3','c3'),
    new Complainces('Complainces4','c4'),
    new Complainces('Complainces5','c5'),
    new Complainces('Complainces6','c6')
    ]
    selectedBudget : Budget = new Budget('Select A Budget','');
    budgets = [
    new Budget('Select A Budget',''),
    new Budget('Budget1','b1'),
    new Budget('Budget2','b2'), 
    new Budget('Budget3','b3'),
    new Budget('Budget4','b4'),
    new Budget('Budget5','b5'),
    new Budget('Budget6','b6')
    ]
    selectedSize : Size = new Size('Size Of Project','');
    sizes = [
    new Size('Size Of Project',''),
    new Size('Size1','s1'),
    new Size('Size2','s2'), 
    new Size('Size3','s3'),
    new Size('Size4','s4'),
    new Size('Size5','s5'),
    new Size('Size6','s6')
    ]
    selectedDuration : Duration = new Duration('Duration Of Project','');
    durations = [
    new Duration('Duration Of Project',''),
    new Duration('Duration1','d1'),
    new Duration('Duration2','d2'), 
    new Duration('Duration3','d3'),
    new Duration('Duration4','d4'),
    new Duration('Duration5','d5'),
    new Duration('Duration6','d6')
    ]
    selectedRole : Role = new Role('Type Of Role','');
    roles = [
    new Role('Type Of Role',''),
    new Role('Role1','r1'),
    new Role('Role2','r2'), 
    new Role('Role3','r3'),
    new Role('Role4','r4'),
    new Role('Role5','r5'),
    new Role('Role6','r6')
    ]


    constructor(private dataService: DataService ) { 

    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    public step1Div = true;
    public ErrorAlert = '';
    Step1(){ 
        if(this.selectedScenario.value === ''){
            this.ErrorAlert = "Please Select Anyone Scenarios"; 
        }else if (this.selectedComplainces.value === '') {

            this.ErrorAlert = "Please Select Anyone Complainces";

        }else if (this.selectedBudget.value === '') {

            this.ErrorAlert = "Please Select Anyone Budget";
        }else if (this.selectedSize.value === '') {

            this.ErrorAlert = "Please Select Anyone Size";

        }else if (this.selectedDuration.value === '') {

            this.ErrorAlert = "Please Select Anyone Duration";

        }else if (this.selectedRole.value === '') {

            this.ErrorAlert = "Please Select Anyone Role";

        }else{

            var step1Data = {"Scenario":this.selectedScenario.value,"Complainces":this.selectedComplainces.value,
            "Size":this.selectedSize.value,"Role":this.selectedRole.value,"Budget":this.selectedBudget.value,
            "Duration":this.selectedDuration.value,};



                this.dataService.getDocs().subscribe((data =>{
                    console.log(data);
                }))
                console.log(step1Data);

                this.step1Div = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Data service .ts**

```
import { CreateProjectsComponent } from '../component/create-projects/create-projects.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {   Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import { Scenario } from '../component/create-projects/step1TS/scenario';
import { Complainces} from '../component/create-projects/step1TS/complainces';
import { Budget } from '../component/create-projects/step1TS/budget';
import { Size } from '../component/create-projects/step1TS/size';
import { Duration } from '../component/create-projects/step1TS/duration';
import { Role } from '../component/create-projects/step1TS/role';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    headers: Headers;
    options: RequestOptions;

    selectedScenario : Scenario = new Scenario('Select A Scenario','');
    scenarios = [
    new Scenario('Select A Scenario',''),
    new Scenario('Scenario1','sc1'),
    new Scenario('Scenario2','sc2'), 
    new Scenario('Scenario3','sc3'),
    new Scenario('Scenario4','sc4'),
    new Scenario('Scenario5','sc5'),
    new Scenario('Scenario6','sc6')
    ]
    selectedComplainces : Complainces = new Complainces('Type Of Complainces','');
    complainces = [
    new Complainces('Type Of Complainces',''),
    new Complainces('Complainces1','c1'),
    new Complainces('Complainces2','c2'), 
    new Complainces('Complainces3','c3'),
    new Complainces('Complainces4','c4'),
    new Complainces('Complainces5','c5'),
    new Complainces('Complainces6','c6')
    ]
    selectedBudget : Budget = new Budget('Select A Budget','');
    budgets = [
    new Budget('Select A Budget',''),
    new Budget('Budget1','b1'),
    new Budget('Budget2','b2'), 
    new Budget('Budget3','b3'),
    new Budget('Budget4','b4'),
    new Budget('Budget5','b5'),
    new Budget('Budget6','b6')
    ]
    selectedSize : Size = new Size('Size Of Project','');
    sizes = [
    new Size('Size Of Project',''),
    new Size('Size1','s1'),
    new Size('Size2','s2'), 
    new Size('Size3','s3'),
    new Size('Size4','s4'),
    new Size('Size5','s5'),
    new Size('Size6','s6')
    ]
    selectedDuration : Duration = new Duration('Duration Of Project','');
    durations = [
    new Duration('Duration Of Project',''),
    new Duration('Duration1','d1'),
    new Duration('Duration2','d2'), 
    new Duration('Duration3','d3'),
    new Duration('Duration4','d4'),
    new Duration('Duration5','d5'),
    new Duration('Duration6','d6')
    ]
    selectedRole : Role = new Role('Type Of Role','');
    roles = [
    new Role('Type Of Role',''),
    new Role('Role1','r1'),
    new Role('Role2','r2'), 
    new Role('Role3','r3'),
    new Role('Role4','r4'),
    new Role('Role5','r5'),
    new Role('Role6','r6')
    ]

    constructor(public http:Http) { 
        console.log('Data Service Connceted');
        this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9' });
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    }
    getDocs(){
        var step1Data = {"Scenario":this.selectedScenario.value,"Complainces":this.selectedComplainces.value,
        "Size":this.selectedSize.value,"Role":this.selectedRole.value,"Budget":this.selectedBudget.value,
        "Duration":this.selectedDuration.value};
        console.log(step1Data);

        let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');   
    let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.set('Scenario' , this.selectedScenario.value);
    myParams.set('Complaines' , this.selectedComplainces.value);
    myParams.set('Duration'  , this.selectedDuration.value);
    myParams.set('Budget' , this.selectedBudget.value);
    myParams.set('Role', this.selectedRole.value);
    myParams.set('Size',this.selectedSize.value);       
    console.log(this.selectedSize.value );
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, params: myParams });
        return this.http.get('http://192.168.0.5:7003/soa-infra/resources/default/SELECT_DOCs1_L!1.0/RestService/',options)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

I am able to console log the data in component but when i did the same in data service its showing empty in value place i didn't understand whats the reason ?
Can Anyone help on this?

I had a look at many of them in stack overflow but it didn't match any of my results?

I had a look at many of them in stack overflow but it didn't match any of my results?

Comment: About which one of console.log()s in dataservice are you talking? the last one?

Comment: which is inside getDocs() Method one  ?

Comment: but the data i should link it to the url

Comment: those are the parameters i need to pass to the  url

Comment: Why do you have the same data repeated in the component and service? also there is too much code, hard to do up and down. maybe you could cut to the essential

Comment: if i post less some are not understanding and asking for the full code so that's why i posted full code i will cut those variables once i m done with the requests

Comment: no, they ask for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example :https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: complete but minimal too

Comment: yeah that's ok can you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

**Service**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class MyDataService {
      constructor(private http: Http){}

      async getHero(){
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8081/getHeros', {headers: headers}).map(response => {
      return response.json() || {success: false, message: "No response from server"};
    }).catch((error: Response | any) => {
      return Observable.throw(error.json());
    }).toPromise();
  }
    }
```

**Components**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild   } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { MyDataService } from '../my-data-service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'angular-async-local-storage';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-form',
  providers: [MyDataService],
  templateUrl: './hero-form.component.html'
})
export class HeroFormComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http, protected storage: AsyncLocalStorage, 
    private router: Router, private newService: MyDataService, private el: 
    ElementRef) {}

    tester  = '';
    async ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoggedIn();
        const response = await this.newService.getHero();
        if(response.status == 'Success'){
        this.Error = '';
        this.Success = response.msg;
        this.tableData = response.data;
    }else {
      this.Success = '';
      this.Error = response.msg;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged. Kindly add some explanation to it.